# (Flags) Marking Non-English Posts as "Rude or Abusive"

Tags: discussion

A few months earlier, when I was going through the "First Posts" section of the review queues, I saw a weird post that was posted as an answer to a question.  The answer was entirely written in **Arabic**, and not **English**, as how it should be on this site.

I flagged this post as "Rude or Abusive", because it would look like some random gibberish to English-speakers.

[image: Flagged it.]

My flag was marked as helpful, and the answer under examination here has been deleted, along with the user who posted it.

So do we accept marking non-English posts as "Rude or Abusive"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A post being in a non-English language does not make it rude or abusive, no. Just mark it as not an answer. If however the content is rude (you can check using Google translate or similar) then flag it as rude.

Answer (score 5):

Being written in a language other than English doesn't necessarily mean a post is rude or abusive, but it's a strong hint. The post you mention also had a weird image in it which was clearly not related to music. "Not an answer" would also apply here.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'd probably flag as a nonanswer, just because I don't know whether it's an answer or not and the readers of this site shouldn't be expected to, either. I'll add, though, that if the post were written in a language that I felt comfortable ***translating*** (and obviously if I knew it realy was an answer), I might overhaul the post into English, leaving a note to the post's author in the comments explaining why I edited. I'm not saying we should expect users to do this, but if there really was a good answer behind the language barrier, I might go above and beyond to translate it.